# Batch rename files to numeric sequence in dired?

Tags: dired

I have the following files in a directory:

```
CIMG4879.JPG
CIMG4880.JPG
CIMG4881.JPG
...
```

I want to rename them all with a numeric sequence such that:

```
01.jpg
02.jpg
03.jpg
...
```

In bash, I could `convert *.JPG %02d.jpg`, since they're all image files.

**How do I do a batch rename in `dired`?**  Assume I have a lot a files, so doing it one by one would be tedious and error-prone.

Comment: One option would be to use shell commands in a `dired-mode` buffer by typing the exclamation point keyboard shortcut:  `!`  You may wish to mark one or more files ahead of time.

Comment: I did not know convert could rename files this way (actually it does create new files with the intended names). I'm not sure what converting a jpg to a jpg means, especially since the sizes of input and output files differ...

Answer (score 10):

Firstly, take note of JeanPierre's comment -- you're *not* renaming files by using `convert` like that. You're creating new and different files (lower quality ones, although the difference may or may not matter in practice, depending on your use-cases).

Here are a few different options for renaming files in dired using a number sequence. The first two are general techniques for editing text, which are applicable thanks to the excellent `wdired-mode`. The third combines dired's rename command with keyboard macro counters.

1. With search-and-replace:

   - <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-q</kbd> (change to editable dired mode; use `C-c C-k` to cancel the edit if you mess anything up)
   - <kbd>C-M-%</kbd> (call `query-replace-regexp`)
   - `CIMG[0-9]+\.JPG` (pattern to match)
   - `\,(format "%02d" (1+ \#)).JPG` (replacement)
   - <kbd>!</kbd> (replace all; or else you could confirm the replacements individually)
   - <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-c</kbd> (to return to normal dired mode, writing the changes)

`\,(...)` calls an elisp function and uses the result in the replacement text; here we are calling `format` on the replacement counter, to which we are first adding one (as it counts from zero).

(It's a shame that `dired-do-rename-regexp` doesn't support that, but not a big deal when you're familiar with `wdired-mode`.)

2. Once again in editable dired mode, mark the filenames as a rectangle, delete the rectangle, then use `rectangle-number-lines` to insert new contents:

   - <kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> call `rectangle-number-lines` with extended argument input
   - Start from 1
   - Use `%02d` as the replacement, being sure to remove the default trailing space (or you could use `%02d.JPG`, depending on what you actually deleted)
3. With keyboard macros, in normal dired:

   - <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-k</kbd><kbd>C-f</kbd> `%02d` (set kmacro counter format)
   - <kbd>M-1</kbd><kbd>F3</kbd> (start recording, initialising counter to 1)
   - <kbd>R</kbd> (dired rename)
   - <kbd>F3</kbd> (insert the current kmacro counter value; the counter then increments)
   - `.JPG` <kbd>RET</kbd> (remainder of the new filename)
   - <kbd>C-n</kbd> (next line)
   - <kbd>F4</kbd> (repeatedly; first to end recording, and then to repeat the macro)

You can use <kbd>M-0</kbd><kbd>F4</kbd> to repeat the macro as many times as possible.

Comment: Great answer. It would be even greater with some pointers on the relevant docs! (since it's the kind of answer that makes one feel one should learn more about that).

Comment: I filed Emacs bug (enhancement request) #[24587](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=24587) , to enable `dired-do-rename-regexp` to fully support `query-replace-regexp` replacement-pattern syntax.

Comment: JeanPierre: Documentation: Type `C-h r` for the manual, `g` to enter an info node by name, and then `Regexp Replace` or `Rectangles` or `Keyboard Macros`.

Comment: @phils with this `\,(format "%02d" (1+ \#)).JPG`, is there anyway I can make it start from 40 instead of 0?

Comment: @William Yes indeed -- simply change `(1+ \#)` to `(+ 40 \#)`.  See `C-h f +` and `C-h f 1+` regarding the slightly different syntax (they're both elisp functions).

Answer (score 2):

> In dired I do not know the regexp

Why bother with dired's regex-replacement? Just enter [wdired-mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Wdired.html) (which I bind to `w` in dired, but default=`C-x C-q`), edit the filenames like regular text, then exit back to normal dired with `C-c C-c`.

Answer (score 1):

```elisp
(defun rename-files-numeric-sequence ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((sequence 1)
        (files (directory-files-recursively default-directory "")))
    (while files
      (rename-file (car files)
                   (format "%s%03d.%s"
                           (file-name-directory (car files))
                           sequence
                           (file-name-extension (car files))))
      (setq files (cdr files))
      (setq sequence (1+ sequence)))))
```

Comment: Good initiative. But this answer seems independent of Dired. Maybe you'd like to add a Dired command that invokes such code but acts, e.g., on the marked files?